# Is it possible to pass a function with parameters as a prop and then reference that function as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make it so when I click on the div, it logs out "asdf" in the console, but I am unsure if this is how methods passed as props work...

```
export class App extends Component {
   render() {
      func = (param) => {
         console.log(param);
      }

      return (
         <Card function={this.func} />
      )
    }
}

export class Card extends Component {
   render() {
      return(
         <div onClick={this.props.function("asdf")}> this is a div </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: This is fine, I just wouldn't use the word `function` as it is reserved. Also note that the way you are doing it here `this` inside func might not be what you are expecting.

Comment: As @MattWay said, you might want to pull `func` out of the `render()` method and define it as a function on `App`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Place your custom method(i.e. `func`) into class scope and remove it from `render()`. Reason I am saying it to remove from `render()` method is when call `this.func` it refers to as `this` points to class's properties and methods. As there will be no `func` property or method defined in global scope of class, it will return `undefined`
- You could pass prop with meaningful name rather than `function` as function could indicate native function keyword as in javascript as Joseph said in his answer

Your code could be updated to this way :

```
export class App extends Component {
    func = param => {
        console.log(param);
    };
    render() {
        return <Card myFunction={this.func} />;
    }
}

export class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={() => this.props.myFunction('asdf')}>
                {' '}
                this is a div{' '}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: My pleasure to provide you an assist

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is fine, but there are two problems with that particular implementation:

1. `function` is a keyword in JavaScript, so don't use it as an identifier.
2. `onClick={foo(bar)}` means "call `foo(bar)` at render time, then make the result of that call be the click handler. You probably want `onClick={() => foo(bar)}`, which means "call foo(bar) when the element is clicked".

Answer (score 1):

Similar advice to Joseph, but would also note that you want to pull your function outside of the `render()` method. Here's what it would look like:

```
export class App extends Component {
  printParam = param => {
    console.log(param);
  };

  render() {
    return <Card printParam={this.printParam} />;
  }
}

export class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          this.props.printParam('asdf');
        }}>
        Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```